# Lower bound independent on $a$ for $\frac{n-2a}{2}\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)^{a-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $a\in (0, 1)$ and $n\in\mathbb N, n\ge 2$ be fixed. I am stuck in proving that there exists a lower bound which does not depend on $a$ (and preferably neither on $n$) for the quantity
$$\frac{n-2a}{2}\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)^{a-1}.$$
To be more precise, I would like to find $c>0$ which does not depend on $a$ such that
$$\frac{n-2a}{2}\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)^{a-1}\ge c$$.

Anyone could help?
I do not know where to start.

Comment: The lower bound is $(n-2)/2$ when $n\le3$ and $\frac{n}{n+2}$ else. Draw a picture of the function or take some derivative, and you can see it. If you want a global bound, then it can only be zero.